# Moodle Mobile 3.7.0

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, apk, moodle

After downloading Moodle Mobile2 from github at https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2 so now its a zip file on my computer. In simple steps how do i get to publish this on googleplay?

I have tried renaming the `zipfile` to .`apk` then used advanced `apktool` to sign and recompile but when uploading to google play i get:-

Upload failed

```
Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found
```

Obviously things are not so simple.  If someone can help me with some basic steps from zip file to apk and publish i would be grateful as i am trying to self learn the process but need some help.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely not so simple as to download the repository :) The detailed steps (from 1 to 9) are listed in the official documentation here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2

Summarizing the documentation and from my own experience you need to:

1. Install all building tools dependencies, at the time I'm writing this (Aug '19) those are: `node v8.12.x or v11.12.x`, `cordova 8.1.2`, `ionic`, `gulp`
2. Install additional tools for MacOSX or Windows if you are using any of those SOs (see doc page linked above).
3. Clone the repository with `git clone` or unzip it after downloading the zipped repository
4. To prepare the iOS and Android platforms (that allows you to build the binaries later on) go inside your project folder (unzipped or cloned folder) and run (from a terminal):

```
$ npm install
$ cordova prepare
$ gulp
```

5. Resolve any compatibility issues among packages that may have arised.
6. Apply the npm packages fixes to build for production with AOT listed in step 9 of the documentation page I linked above.
7. Build the apk from the terminal:

```
$ npm run ionic:build -- --prod
$ cordova build android --release
```

At this point you will have the compiled apk ready to be signed and uploaded to the Google Store.